# How can I invoke a method without knowing the count of parameters using java.lang.reflect?

Tags: java, reflection, variadic-functions

I read a tutorial about java.öang.reflect and found a way to get a method from a class and invoke it with given parameters like that:

```
Method method = /*some initialization*/;
Object returnValue = method.invoke(null, "parameter-value1");
```

This calls the static method "method" which takes "parameter-value1" as its only parameter.

Now that's pretty neat, but it is not sufficiently dynamic. I want to invoke a method I only have the method-object of and insert an unspecified number of parameters. Let's say I have `Method method` and `Object[] parameters` (to be used as parameters for the invocation of `method`).

Is it possible to write a short and simple method to call any method with given arguments by using reflect? If so: How to archieve this?

Comment: The number of parameters is know. In fact we even know the types of the parameters: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes%28%29

Comment: Well, that's exactly what Method.invoke expects: a target object to call the method on (null if it's static), and an array of arguments: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: `Method.invoke` takes an `Object` representing the instance and a varargs of `Object` representing the parameters. I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you are asking is already implemented in Method.invoke, you can just pass in an array of parameters

Comment: You need to read the Javadoc. `Method.invoke(Object object, Object...parameters)`.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible. You **can** invoke the method with a given `Object[]` as parameters. But there are some constraints on that:

- the number of parameters must match the number of parameters of the method, so it's not possible to call it with an arbitrary number of parameters. Well, it's possible but you won't get anything except for an exception thrown.
- the types of the parameters must match the required parameter-types of the method. Same as above, invalid parameter-types lead to an exception.

Luckily both of these are known, thanks to [`Method#getParameterTypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes%28%29):

```
Class<?>[] parameterTypes = someMethod.getParameterTypes();
int parameterCount = parameterTypes.length;
```

Comment: The number of parameters and their types is no problem as I can check that before I invoke the method.
You see, here [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html] it says that it is possible to use a variable amount of parameters: `invoke(Object obj, Object... args)`
But does it also take `Object[]` instead of `Object...`?

Example: `method.invoke(none, new Object[]{"foo",42});` when `method` invokes `public static void printStrAndInt(String s, Integer i) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: @ChaosNe0 In that case you should specify what you exactly want to do... a code-example would be pretty helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to enter a new line in the comment but it got posted, so I changed the last one.

Comment: @ChaosNe0 so this question isn't about reflection, but varargs? Why don't you simply test it?

Comment: Excuse me, it seems so. I looked for a matching method in the reflection-api but this seems to be my real problem. (In my defence: I didn't know of varargs before.)

Comment: @ChaosNe0 note exactly the most recent article, but it's from oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html . In short: yes, it's possible.

Comment: Thank you, I just did a little testing and it works like a charm. I guess I have to mess a bit more around next time.

Comment: @ChaosNe0 glad to help you :)